# New help on developing code to trigger a script i already have

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi im very very new to this.
I already have a script in Google Sheets that is working perfectly.

What i want to do now is trigger that same script whenever a cell value exceeds the value of 100.

Can anyone help as ive spent days researching to no avail

Like i said im very new to this so please treat me like a dummy LOL

Cheers

Comment: Only user edits can trigger functions when a value is changed. If you use a formula or script to update the value then the onEdit trigger is not going to work . Another solution would be to use a time driven trigger to check every minute or so the value of the cell and if the value is more than 100 then run some code.

Comment: yeah i get what your saying but no idea how to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a time-based trigger that fires every 5 minutes. The trigger will call the function that will have the task of checking the values ​​of the cells of your interest and when it finds a value of 100 it will perform the desired operation.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry im pretty new t this. Im not really sure how to write the code for that? Are you able to give me an idea?

Comment: To add a trigger you do not need to write code, access the triggers section from the editor interface and configure it manually.